# java -jar can't find included .jar file

Tags: java, jar, noclassdeffounderror

I'm tearing what little hair I have left over this one: any help will be extremely gratefully received!

I have constructed a .jar file (called, rather uninspiringly, compare-yaml.jar) with the following contents

```
 META-INF/
 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
 YamlParser.class
 snakeyaml-1.28.jar
```

MANIFEST.MF contains the following:

```
 Manifest-Version: 1.0
 Main-Class: YamlParser
 Class-Path: snakeyaml-1.28.jar
 Created-By: 11.0.12 (Oracle Corporation)
```

The Java class compares two Yaml files, although that is incidental.

When I run the .jar file with the command

```
 java -jar compare-yaml.jar a.yaml b.yaml
```

I get the output

```
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/yaml/snakeyaml/Yaml
        at YamlParser.readFileIntoMap(YamlParser.java:29)
        at YamlParser.main(YamlParser.java:58)
  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
        ... 2 more
```

However, if I unpack the jar so that snakeyaml-1.28.jar is on the same directory as compare-yaml.jar, the program runs correctly.

So why isn't the jar command picking up snakeyaml-1.28.jar on the classpath when it's in the containing jar?

TIA,

Graeme

Comment: Because the [Class-Path attribute](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/specs/jar/jar.html#class-path-attribute) contains a space-separated list of URLs *relative to the containing jar file.*  A relative URL cannot refer to something inside the base URL, only something alonside the base URL.

Answer (score 0):

The classpath isn't actually recursive: It only checks the top level of classes. Jar-in-jar dependencies aren't supported by java itself.

There's a nice plugin for gradle called [`shadowJar`](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow), that bundles all dependencies automatically into the final jar, maybe that'll help you out here.

Other than that, you'll have to manually bundle dependency jars in another folder, and include them into the classpath at runtime.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand that - should I expand the snakeyaml jar file? According to the Java docs at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html you can specify a .jar file inside a .jar file.

Comment: @GraemeBurton java doesn't find the classes you want it to find because you're putting a whole jar in another jar, which java alone doesn't grasp correctly. You need to essentially unbox the dependency jar and put all classes from it into your jarfile. This is also called a "fat" or "uber" jar.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean - I've had another look at the Oracle documentation and read it properly this time! Thank you - your input is very much appreciated.

Comment: @GraemeBurton Jar files have to be on the classpath, not arbitrarily included in app jar file. You **can** do that (e.g., oneJar or a homebrew solution) but über-jars are more typical (and more easily supported).

Comment: @0x150 Now sorted - thank you!

Comment: UberJar would be an alternative solution that packages dependencies. A shaded-jar is a bit safer as it renames dependencies to avoid dependency version mismatch.